# MS Access Set Parameter Query

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to run an Access query that filters a RawData table  by Site.

When I run the query normally it runs fine, I have set up the query as follows

[image: Picture of Relevant Fields from Query]

I have a sub table in the database that contains the names of the Sites and am using VBA to run through the Site list in this table and do certain actions including filtering the Raw Data Table (via the Query) and copying the raw data to an excel sheet.

I am trying to incorporate my Access query into the Access VBA and it's falling down here

```
DoCmd.SetParameter "[Enter the Site:]", rs!DimensionSite
DoCmd.OpenQuery "Raw Data Filtered by Site"
```

rs!DimensionSite is the relevant field from the 'DimensionSite' column in the Site table

I am getting an error on the first line saying " the expression you entered contains invalid syntax"

I'm not sure in the setparameter text if I should be referencing (1) 'DimensionSite' (i.e. the column name within the table) or (2) 'Enter the Site:', i.e. the text box criteria I am using in the query.

I would appreciate any help with what is going wrong

Thanks

J

Comment: Your code looks fine. Does the problem still occur if you use a "simple" parameter name such as "[Site]" instead of "[Enter the Site:]"? (Note that you need to change it both in the query and in your code.)

Comment: Try replacing `rs!DimensionSite` with an existing value. If that runs (it should), the record holds no existing value if any.

Comment: Hi Heinzi.  DoCmd.SetParameter "[Site]", rs!DimensionSite, and changed to [Site] in the Query also, but still get the same message

Comment: Hi Gustav, I tried replacing one of the rs!DimensionSite with one of the Site Names and still get the same error message. i tried using this DoCmd.SetParameter "[Site]", "Site1", but doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: I haven't used `DoCmd.SetParameter`, but you may have to explicitely specify the parameter name and data type in `Query design -> Parameters`.

Comment: Since you already have the values in your record set, why use a parameter at all?  Remove the parameter and run the query as an SQL statement.  DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * FROM [Raw Data Filtered by Site] WHERE [Dimension Site] = " & rs!DimenstionSite (or something similar to that effect.)

Answer (score 1):

After hitting the same problem. I have discovered the example provided by Microsoft throws you in the wrong direction.

You need to surround in " when you are using string parameters.

For your example use:

```
DoCmd.SetParameter "[Enter the Site:]", """" & rs!DimensionSite & """"
```